# Enumerated type and registers

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm having difficulties with some code, basically I need to fill 3 vectors that work as data storage, where every vector position correspond to a specific province, I'm sorry about the variable names being in spanish.

```
CONST
F = 24;
            
TYPE
T_vector = array [1..F] of Real;
subrango = 1..F;
            
registro_infectados = record
name, email, date_of_birth,estado: string[30];
street, city, provincia: string[30];
street_number, pc,: integer;
id,phone_number:real;
end;
T_archivo_infectados = FILE OF registro_infectados;
        
PROCEDURE INFECTADOS_POR_PROVINCIA(VAR arch:T_archivo_infectados; VAR vect_activos:t_vector; VAR vect_fallecidos: t_vector; VAR vect_recuperados:t_vector); // This will read every register, count the "reg.state" and sum 1 to the corresponding vector.
    var
        
    lim:subrango;
    REG:registro_infectados;
    
    Begin
        
Inicializar_Vector(vect_activos, vect_fallecidos, vect_recuperados, lim); //This iniatiate the vectors.
RESET(ARCH); 
        
Begin
        
   WHILE NOT(EOF(ARCH)) DO
   BEGIN
    
        READ(ARCH, REG);
            
        case reg.estado of
        'activo':begin
                case reg.provincia of
                            'Entre Rios': vect_activos[1]:= vect_activos[1] + 1 ;
                            'Buenos Aires':vect_activos[2]:= vect_activos[2] + 1;
                            'Cordoba': vect_activos[3]:= vect_activos[3] + 1;
                            'Corrientes': vect_activos[4]:= vect_activos[4] + 1 ;
                            'Misiones': vect_activos[5]:= vect_activos[5] + 1 ;
                            'Formosa': vect_activos[6]:= vect_activos[6] + 1 ;
                            'Chaco': vect_activos[7]:= vect_activos[7] + 1 ;
                            'Jujuy': vect_activos[8]:= vect_activos[8] + 1 ;
                            'Salta': vect_activos[9]:= vect_activos[9] + 1 ;
                            'Tucuman': vect_activos[10]:= vect_activos[10] + 1 ;
                            'La Rioja': vect_activos[11]:= vect_activos[11] + 1 ;
                            'Santiago del Estero': vect_activos[12]:= vect_activos[12] + 1 ;
                            'Catamarca': vect_activos[13]:= vect_activos[13] + 1 ;
                            'La Pampa': vect_activos[14]:= vect_activos[14] + 1 ;
                            'Santa Fe': vect_activos[15]:= vect_activos[15] + 1 ;
                            'Mendoza': vect_activos[16]:= vect_activos[16] + 1 ;
                            'San Juan': vect_activos[17]:= vect_activos[17] + 1 ;
                            'Rio Negro': vect_activos[18]:= vect_activos[18] + 1 ;
                            'Tierra del Fuego': vect_activos[19]:= vect_activos[19] + 1 ;
                            'Santa Cruz': vect_activos[20]:= vect_activos[20] + 1 ;
                            'Chubut': vect_activos[21]:= vect_activos[21] + 1 ;
                            'San Luis': vect_activos[22]:= vect_activos[22] + 1 ;
                            'Neuquen': vect_activos[23]:= vect_activos[23] + 1 ;
                            'CABA': vect_activos[24] := vect_activos[24] + 1;
                            end;
                         end;
                         
                'fallecido': begin
                                case reg.provincia of
                                
                            'Entre Rios': vect_fallecidos[1]:= vect_fallecidos[1] + 1 ;
                            'Buenos Aires':vect_fallecidos[2]:= vect_fallecidos[2] + 1;
                            'Cordoba': vect_fallecidos[3]:= vect_fallecidos[3] + 1;
                            'Corrientes': vect_fallecidos[4]:= vect_fallecidos[4] + 1 ;
                            'Misiones': vect_fallecidos[5]:= vect_fallecidos[5] + 1 ;
                            'Formosa': vect_fallecidos[6]:= vect_fallecidos[6] + 1 ;
                            'Chaco': vect_fallecidos[7]:= vect_fallecidos[7] + 1 ;
                            'Jujuy': vect_fallecidos[8]:= vect_fallecidos[8] + 1 ;
                            'Salta': vect_fallecidos[9]:= vect_fallecidos[9] + 1 ;
                            'Tucuman': vect_fallecidos[10]:= vect_fallecidos[10] + 1 ;
                            'La Rioja': vect_fallecidos[11]:= vect_fallecidos[11] + 1 ;
                            'Santiago del Estero': vect_fallecidos[12]:= vect_fallecidos[12] + 1 ;
                            'Catamarca': vect_fallecidos[13]:= vect_fallecidos[13] + 1 ;
                            'La Pampa': vect_fallecidos[14]:= vect_fallecidos[14] + 1 ;
                            'Santa Fe': vect_fallecidos[15]:= vect_fallecidos[15] + 1 ;
                            'Mendoza': vect_fallecidos[16]:= vect_fallecidos[16] + 1 ;
                            'San Juan': vect_fallecidos[17]:= vect_fallecidos[17] + 1 ;
                            'Rio Negro': vect_fallecidos[18]:= vect_fallecidos[18] + 1 ;
                            'Tierra del Fuego': vect_fallecidos[19]:= vect_fallecidos[19] + 1 ;
                            'Santa Cruz': vect_fallecidos[20]:= vect_fallecidos[20] + 1 ;
                            'Chubut': vect_fallecidos[21]:= vect_fallecidos[21] + 1 ;
                            'San Luis': vect_fallecidos[22]:= vect_fallecidos[22] + 1 ;
                            'Neuquen': vect_fallecidos[23]:= vect_fallecidos[23] + 1 ;
                            'CABA': vect_fallecidos[24] := vect_fallecidos[24] + 1;
                                
                                end;
                            end;
                'recuperado': begin
                                case reg.provincia of
                                
                            'Entre Rios': vect_recuperados[1]:= vect_recuperados[1] + 1 ;
                            'Buenos Aires':vect_recuperados[2]:= vect_recuperados[2] + 1;
                            'Cordoba': vect_recuperados[3]:= vect_recuperados[3] + 1;
                            'Corrientes': vect_recuperados[4]:= vect_recuperados[4] + 1 ;
                            'Misiones': vect_recuperados[5]:= vect_recuperados[5] + 1 ;
                            'Formosa': vect_recuperados[6]:= vect_recuperados[6] + 1 ;
                            'Chaco': vect_recuperados[7]:= vect_recuperados[7] + 1 ;
                            'Jujuy': vect_recuperados[8]:= vect_recuperados[8] + 1 ;
                            'Salta': vect_recuperados[9]:= vect_recuperados[9] + 1 ;
                            'Tucuman': vect_recuperados[10]:= vect_recuperados[10] + 1 ;
                            'La Rioja': vect_recuperados[11]:= vect_recuperados[11] + 1 ;
                            'Santiago del Estero': vect_recuperados[12]:= vect_recuperados[12] + 1 ;
                            'Catamarca': vect_recuperados[13]:= vect_recuperados[13] + 1 ;
                            'La Pampa': vect_recuperados[14]:= vect_recuperados[14] + 1 ;
                            'Santa Fe': vect_recuperados[15]:= vect_recuperados[15] + 1 ;
                            'Mendoza': vect_recuperados[16]:= vect_recuperados[16] + 1 ;
                            'San Juan': vect_recuperados[17]:= vect_recuperados[17] + 1 ;
                            'Rio Negro': vect_recuperados[18]:= vect_recuperados[18] + 1 ;
                            'Tierra del Fuego': vect_recuperados[19]:= vect_recuperados[19] + 1 ;
                            'Santa Cruz': vect_recuperados[20]:= vect_recuperados[20] + 1 ;
                            'Chubut': vect_recuperados[21]:= vect_recuperados[21] + 1 ;
                            'San Luis': vect_recuperados[22]:= vect_recuperados[22] + 1 ;
                            'Neuquen': vect_recuperados[23]:= vect_recuperados[23] + 1 ;
                            'CABA': vect_recuperados[24] := vect_recuperados[24] + 1;
                                end;
                              end;
                              
                end;
                end;
                end;
    
        
    End;
```

The code is working just fine, but I'm afraid is too long and I can't come up with a solution to make it shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the actual problem,as We dont have all the functions

All your parameters are declared as variables, which means that, all new values will be in the same varables, and as you know procedures do not return* values.

Example:

```
procedure INFECTED_BY_PROVINCE(VAR X : Integer);
begin
 X := 12345; // will set the incoming variable to that value
end;

VAR
 TestVar : Integer;

begin
 TestVar := 0; /// Set X to 0
 INFECTED_BY_PROVINCE(TestVar);
 writeln(TestVar); // Output/TestVar will be 12345; 
end.
```

Comment: What I need to do is to write a procedure that counts and stores the state data from every pacient by province inside the 3 vectors, where every vector position correspond to a specific province, ie active_vector[1] = province1. deceased_vector[2] = province2

Comment: Have you checked is that var REG:infected_register; is filled properly,because i dont think so, are you working with CSV files, and are you going to update them, i am asking as i dont think you can do with only with WHILE NOT(EOF(ARCH)) and READ... and if you only want to count you can read the whole line and use Pos to determine the state

Comment: I'm working with DAT files, The reg properly filled, I've come up with a solution but it's not "pretty" since I'm using a case of insde of another case of, I'll modify the question so I can upload the new solution.

Comment: In that case, your new values should be in the same variable, did't notice it for some reason province_code:= Ord(reg.province); should be in inside the while

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeating the `case REG.provincia of` block for each `REG.estado`, do it only once and assign a variable, e.g. `indx: integer` a value that corresponds to the province:

```
var
  lim: subrango;
  REG: registro_infectados;

  indx: integer;  // new variable

    case REG.provincia of
      'Entre Rios':   indx := 1;
      'Buenos Aires': indx := 2;
      'Cordoba':      indx := 3;
      //
      //... fill in all other provinces
      //
      'CABA':         indx := 24;
    end;
```

Now you can simplify the assignment to the vectors for the three states (`REG.estado`) using the province `indx` to just a few lines:

```
    case REG.estado of
      'activo':     inc(vect_activos[indx]);
      'fallecido':  inc(vect_fallecidos[indx]);
      'recuperado': inc(vect_recuperados[indx]);
    end;
```

As you see, using `inc()` also shortens the assignment.